# Wordpress template part show only selected posts from post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this template part:

```
 <?php
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'page');
        do_action('flash_before_comment_template');

        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
        if (comments_open() || get_comments_number()) :
            comments_template();
        endif;

        do_action('flash_after_comment_template');

    endwhile; // End of the loop.
    ?>
```

And I have a Post Type named food. I want to show only thoose posts (post with title and whole body) which contains this Post type. How should I modify the template to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom post type get the query

```
<?php  

$custom_args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'food',
    'orderby'       => 'post_date',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1

    );

    $get_news_query = new WP_Query( $custom_args ); ?>

    <?php if ( $get_news_query->have_posts() ) : ?>


        <?php while ( $get_news_query->have_posts() ) : $get_news_query->the_post(); ?>



            <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else:  ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; 

wp_reset_query();
?>
```